# jquery ui 1.10.2 show easing doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, show-hide

Since I have upgraded from **jquery-ui 1.8** to **1.10.2**, the **`.show( effect [, options ] [, duration ] [, complete ] )`** doesn't work anymore.

I could replace:

```
$(this).show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);
```

with

```
$(this).effect("slide");
```

but when I replace:

```
$(Elt).show("blind", {direction: "vertical"}, 500);
```

with

```
$(Elt).effect("blind");
```

`$(Elt)` disappears after the `"blind"` effect.  And if I append `.show()`, it's ignored.

I found some kind of clues at http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/ about `$.effects[]` (at the end of the page) but it doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: First time I make one:  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pr5nA/).  Works OK with jq 1.x (UI 1.8.5 or 1.8.9) and jq 1.7.2 (UI 1.8.18).

Comment: In my code, problem arises with **jquery-1.9.0.js** with **UI 1.10.2** and **jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js** from **code.jquery.com**.  All worked well until I replaced the old **UI 1.8** library.

Comment: I resolved my problem and I hope it can help others...  It seems that starting with jQuery UI 1.9, **show() ignore effects** and possibly other parameters **if the object is already displayed** whereas it was ok to do so with jQuery UI 1.8.  Sorry for the trouble, Mooseman. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you want to do.

With this you can show the `selectedObject` by sliding it in with the easing and direction you prefer:

```
$(selectedObject).show("slide", { easing: "TransitionName", direction: "left" }, 500);
```

with this other you can hide the same `selectedObject` by sliding it out:

```
$(selectedObject).hide("slide", { easing: "TransitionName", direction: "right" }, 500);
```

Hope I could help you.

Comment: The first line of the question states that this is precisely what doesn't work since the OP upgraded to jquery 1.10.2.